# Evaluating a sub expression does not give interpolated variable

Tags: bash, sh

```
v_msg=`echo "$v_msg" | sed 's/To: root/To: $v_recipient/g'`
```

if $v_msg is "To: root", and $v_recipient is "me@mydomain.com" then it ends up being "To: $v_recipient".... where as I want it to be "To: me@mydomain.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double quotes if you want string interpolation and I'd recommend `$()` over backticks when available:

```
v_msg=$(echo "$v_msg" | sed "s/To: root/To: $v_recipient/g")
```